# Error: A table can't overlap another table in Interop.Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop, excel-interop

I am getting error `A table can't overlap another table`

I am trying to write and same time format table once few lines are written. Table formatting is part of for loop.

**Approach 1:**

```
Range range = (Range)sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[fromRow, fromCol], sheet.Cells[toRow, toCol]];
ListObject x = sheet.ListObjects.AddEx(XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range, Missing.Value, XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Missing.Value);
x.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9";
```

Iteration 1: Passed

```
fromRow = 3, fromCol = 2, toRow = 187, toCol = 8 // Passed
```

Iteration 2: Failed

```
fromRow = 189, fromCol = 2, toRow = 271, toCol = 8 // Failed
```

**Approach 2:**

```
string r = GetExcelRangeName(fromRow, fromCol, toRow, toCol);
Range range = (Range)sheet.get_Range(r);
ListObject x = sheet.ListObjects.AddEx(XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range, Missing.Value, XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Missing.Value);
x.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9";
```

Iteration 1: Passed

```
r = "B3:H187" // Passed
```

Iteration 2: Failed

```
r = "B189:H271" //Failed
```

This very hard to debug. Please help.

Comment: Getting error in 2nd iteration at while executing line ```ListObject x =sheet.ListObjects.AddEx(XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range, Missing.Value, XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Missing.Value);```

Comment: Even if I'm giving unique names by ```.Name``` property every time in debug, still facing same problem.

Comment: If I'm giving ```toRow - 1``` then its working but of course leaving last row from all tables.

Comment: How can ```"B3:H187"``` and ```"B189:H271"``` overlap?